# Giving a link in a asp.net mvc2 page for a non-mvc page ie, a asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I tried to give link to my reports located in Reports folder under "Views". My problem is that I am unable to direct from a mvc page to myReport since it is looking for that page in controller, which doesnt exist. I have the route given in global.asax. am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

my mapping to web pages is as follows

aspx page (contains relative path to the application eg:

```
   <siteMapNode url="Managers/FindUser.aspx" title="Find user"/>
```

**is translated as :http://localhost/Managers/FindUser.aspx**

mvc page

```
  <siteMapNode url="Managers/Management/" title="Management" />
```

**is translated as :http://localhost/Managers/Management/**